# Как сделать буквы заглавными PHP

Tags: php

```
$word = "word"
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы случайные буквы делались заглавными?
Например:

```
$word = "wOrD"
```

или

```
$word = "woRd"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function up($in_word){
    $str_count = strlen($in_word); // количествo символов в строке
    $n = mt_rand(0, $str_count-1); // генерируем случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до количества символов в строке
    $letter = $in_word{$n}; // буква для которой меняем регистр
    $up = strtoupper($letter); // меняем регистр случайной буквы

    return str_replace("$letter", "$up", $in_word); // меняем букву в слове на заглавную
}

$word = "word"
echo up($word); // меняем одну букву
echo up(up($word)); // меняем несколько букв. Количество вызовов равно максимальному количеству заглавных букв
```

Answer (score 2):

> Как можно сделать так, чтобы случайные буквы делались заглавными?

Вот ещё один пример в коллекцию:

```
$word = "word";

for($i = 0; $i< strlen($word); $i++) {
    if (rand(0,1)) {
        $word[$i]=strtoupper($word[$i]);
    }
}

echo $word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Пройтись по буквам и собрать новое слово

```
$word = "word";
$wordarr = str_split($word);
$word = "";

foreach($wordarr as $ltr) {
    if (rand(0,1) == 1) {
        $word .= $ltr;
    } else {
        $word .=strtoupper($ltr);
    }
}

echo $word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$word = "word";

$s = str_split($word);
$rand = rand(0, count($s) - 1);

$word{$rand} = strtoupper($word{$rand});

echo $word;
```

Comment: надо чтобы минимум 2 или 3 были заглавными, такое возможно?

Comment: можно. пресчитай буквы и повтори

Comment: @НиколайВасиленков, можно циклом `N` количество раз повторить.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать данные команды с перебором строки как массива

```
lcfirst() - Преобразует первый символ строки в нижний регистр
strtolower() - Преобразует строку в нижний регистр
strtoupper() - Преобразует строку в верхний регистр
ucwords() - Преобразует в верхний регистр первый символ каждого слова в строке
```